# C++: How to make an array global accessible?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size, global-variables

How do I make an array global accessible (e.g. by pointer) if I have to compute its size from `argv` first?

```
#include <cstdlib> // atoi

int *p[];

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = atoi (argv[1]);
    int i[x];
    p = &i;
}
```

error: storage size of ‘p’ isn’t known

Comment: you're assigning an address of a `int` array to an unsized array  of pointers to int. the types aren't compatible. Is there reason you're not just using `int *p;` and `p = i;` ? (I mean beyond the terrible idea of doing any of this with pointers and globals in the first place)? I'm assuming you're using gcc, because that variable-length-array isn't standard C++ regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> p;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) { return 1; }   // make sure argv[1] exists!

    p.resize(std::stoi(argv[1]));

    // ...
}
```

(There are many ways of parsing a string into an integer; pick whichever one suits your needs best, e.g. consider error handling.)

Answer (score 0):

The size of i have be known in compile time.

In this case, you should allocate memory in runtime. 
You have to do like this:

```
int i[] = new int[x];
p=&i;
```

When p is not used anymore, you have to release the memory to prevent memory leaks.

```
delete[] (*p);
```

And the whole program:

```
#include <cstdlib> // atoi

int *p[];

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = atoi (argv[1]);
    int i[] = new int[x];
    p=&i;

     //do whatever you want

     delete[] (*p);
     return 0;
}
```